# issues with text box value changes

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, textbox

I have a TextBox, 
The situation is that when a user leaves it empty, OK button is disabled. If user types in a value of duration based on days, the button gets enabled.

The problem is: let's say the user clicks on text box, types in : 100, and he realizes that he made a mistake, he erase that value and tries to start filling some other textboxes and come back again afterwards, at this level at the time user clicks on other part of form, the value becoems 0 autoamtically and Ok button is Enabled Now.

How can I avoid this?

```
Private Sub txtMembershipDuration_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtMembershipDuration.TextChanged
If txtMembershipDuration.Text = "" Then
  btnOK.Enabled = False
End If  End Sub
```

Also, how can I control that auttomatic 0?

Comment: The value will not "automatically" become 0 unless you've **written code** to set the value to 0. Thus, the simple way to avoid it is to remove that code.

Comment: Where/When is the value being set to 0??

Comment: I see you've edited your question to ask about the 0 again, but the problem wasn't a lack of clarity. I understood that was the problem you were trying to solve. But I need you to help me help you. *Somehow*, you've written code that inserts a 0 into the textbox. That's the only way to make that happen "automatically". Do a search in your form class for all assignments to `txtMembershipDuration.Text` and show any code that produces a hit.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `TryParse` on your check, and make sure it's greater than 0, instead of checking if it's "".
[Link: TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)

Comment: TryParse is a good recommendation for input validation and additionally checking for invalid numbers is a good idea too.

Comment: How about that Val? I really don't think it is a secure way for value casting. Is it?

Comment: It's pretty secure. It's not a Parse, it's TryParse. Maybe you're confusing them. TryParse will return a boolean value if the conversion succeeded, the actual value will be returned with an out param.

Comment: I know the security of TryParse, I am wondering about security of Val Method.

Comment: Seems like Val is not as tight as TryParse if you look at the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9da280t0.aspx Some combinations of numbers & letters may cause Runtime exceptions. Also input with text & numbers would end up getting returned as valid input, which is something which I should avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for "0" if it's not a valid value

```
Private Sub txtMembershipDuration_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles txtMembershipDuration.TextChanged
    If txtMembershipDuration.Text = "" OrElse
       txtMembershipDuration.Text = "0" Then
        btnOK.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @J. Vermeire: I don't see what's so "dirty" about it. It doesn't strike me as any less elegant than doing a `TryParse` each time. It's probably more performant, as well.

Comment: Because a TryParse would also catch other faulty input (such as text), where the code above would not. Especially new programmers should try to think things trough instead of taking the easy obvious solution. It might benefit them in the long run. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes But the situtaion is that where the hell that 0 came from?

Comment: @J. Vermeire: No, I agree about thinking things through, regardless even of one's experience. Had you explained that it wouldn't catch other faulty input in your comment, I would have been more likely to agree with you. The point is that you should always write code for a specific reason, rather than just copy-and-pasting it from a Q&A site. :-)

Comment: @Faulty: Like I said in a comment to your question, 0s don't just appear out of nowhere in a textbox that the user left blank. You've obviously written code somewhere to insert a 0. It's not in the code that you've shown, so check the other event handler methods on your form.

Comment: thanks, i edited my question! Any advise for that stupid 0 showing?